# What is a word for a concept that is understood across almost all languages?

Tags: single-word-requests, concept

This questions is probably strange, but I will give an example. The concept of money, for example is understood by almost all languages, or take the concept of mathematics. Is there an actual word for this?

Comment: Do you mean in translation?? Yes, universal concepts.

Comment: is there no good single-word equivalent for "universal concepts" though?

Comment: Yes, universals.

Comment: You mean in the sense that mathematics functions as a [lingua franca](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lingua%20franca)?

Comment: that would be describing more than one concept though, wouldn't it? As in, "the universals of money" doesn't seem to make sense as money is a single concept. "The universality of money" would make make grammatical sense but is not as useful as "the universal concept of money"

Comment: 'Money' is a universal concept? That's a pretty modern invention, like writing.

Comment: There is [Swadesh list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swadesh_list).

Comment: Most people use more than one word, at least one of which is often *transcending* ...

Comment: I question your premise. Although a given concept may be expressed more easily in one language than in another, you haven't established that language is a barrier to understanding any given concept. After all, it's the person that does the understanding; the language simply encodes it. Can you name a concept comprehensible in English that isn't comprehensible in most other languages?

Comment: universals such as mediums of exchange like money, coins, tokens or  goats [joke].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omni-cultural.

Meaning a word or concept that is understood across all cultures.

Omni means 'all, of all things'

https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=omni+meaning&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-sg&client=safari

Cultural means 'relating to the ideas, customs and social behaviour of a society'.

https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=cultural+means&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-sg&client=safari

Examples:

- Money is an omni-cultural concept, understood globally
- the United Nations creates omni-cultural programmes for global education, peace and wellbeing
- 'why omni-culturalism not multi-culturalism is the solution'

https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/the-psychology-dictatorship/201407/why-omniculturalism-not-multiculturalism-is-the-solution